# How to detect Device Orientation before viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, orientation, device, uiinterfaceorientation

I need to detect device orientation before running viewDidLoad method in controller. I tried all solutions purposed in other questions but I can't solve.

What's the best way using SotryBoard in xCode 5 and iOS 7 to do that?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Actually I'm using

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

        switch ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]) {
            case (UIDeviceOrientationPortrait):
                // landscape layout
                break;

            default:
                // portrait layout
                break;
        }
```

but it does't work...

SOLVED: using

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        // Portrait
    }

    if( [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
        // Landscape
    }
}
```

Comment: do not confuse UIDeviceOrientation and UIInterfaceOrientation

Comment: You shouldn't be doing layout in `viewDidLoad`.  Here you can set up data models and initialize views, but all of your layout should be done in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, where `self.view.frame` will accurately represent the current frame, accounting for rotation.

Comment: Does it also work with storyBoard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking the status bar orientation:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
```

Also there are a few other view controller methods fired before viewDidLoad. Look at awakeFromNib and initWithCoder.

Comment: if status bar is Hidden this not working any other Suggestion you have please share it Thank you Ans...

Answer (score 3):

`[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` is what you need?

Comment: This probably won't work without a call to `[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications]`